# Two limits with trigonometric functions as $x\to\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

1. Is  $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty}⁡\frac{3\cos x}{x+5}$ equal to $+∞$?
2. Is  $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty}\left(x\sin{(\pi /x)}\right)$  equal to $1$?

I'm not sure how to go about solving this problem.

Comment: Do you mean $\cos x$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first case, $|\cos x|\le1$ for real $x$

For the second, set $\dfrac\pi x=h,$ $$\lim_{x\to\infty}x\sin\frac\pi x=\pi\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin h}h$$

Comment: for second does it equal π or 1 ?

Comment: @user155971,Could you follow  my short argument ?

Comment: yes, I followed and given me 1 as (sinh/h)=1

Comment: @user155971, where is the confusion ?

Comment: yes it's pi , sorry about this mistake

Answer (score 1):

I gather $cox$ is $\cos(x)$.
For 1) you can use 2 easy arguments, first, $\cos$ is bounded and $x \to \frac{1}{x+5}$ have 0 for limit when $x$ tends toward $\infty$ then you have a product of a bounded function by an infinitesimal function, so you your product is infinitesimal.
Or you can use $-1\leq \cos(x) \leq 1$ and so $\frac{-1}{x+5} \leq \frac{\cos(x)}{x+5} \leq \frac{1}{x+5}$ and you'll have the same answer.

For 2), remember that $\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin(h)}{h}=1$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x}=0$

Comment: $\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{sin(h)}{h}=1$

Comment: Oops yes, my mistake. :) ty